# selectTag() is not prepending to label in CFWheels

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

In my CFWheels `settings.cfm`, I have the following code:

```
set(functionName="selecttag",       labelPlacement="before", prependToLabel="<div class='field field-select'>",     append="</div>", appendToLabel="", class="field-select");
set(functionName="select",          labelPlacement="before", prependToLabel="<div class='field field-select'>",     append="</div>", appendToLabel="", class="field-select");
```

In my form view I have the following code:

```
<cfoutput>#selectTag(name="pin[typeid]", options=types, objectName="pin", property="typeid")#</cfoutput>
```

However, in the generated output, the HTML within the `prependToLabel` attribute is not outputted. The `append` attribute **is** working though; which of course breaks the formatting / layout of the page.

**Output HTML**

```
<select class="field-select" id="pin-typeid" name="pin[typeid]"><option value="1">Wanted</option><option value="2">Available</option></select></div>
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something incorrectly here?

Thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER!**

In my view, I needed to add the label attribute, which I had forgotten to do.

```
label=""
```

So, my view code should have actually been:

```
<cfoutput>#selectTag( label="Type of Pin", name="pin[typeid]", options=types, objectName="pin", property="typeid" )#</cfoutput>
```

The generated HTML now works / outputs as expected.